# Transfer big file to Azure account inside BizSpark

Tags: azure, data-transfer, data-transfer-objects, bizspark

I have a BizSpark account for my company and we need to transfer a big images file to be used in our website database later. The file is about 550 GB, and I need to transfer it to one of free BizSpark Azure accounts. 
We are new to BizSpark and Azure, so any tips will be much appreciated. 
The ones who will transfer the file asks us to provide them with FTP details like server name, username, and password.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I assume you are going to use a storage account for this job, right?

Comment: Yes, storage account, VM, or any other solution will be okay for now.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you two ways to upload content to Azure Storage.

1) Using Free Storage Tools.These are the two that i use but you have other options including paid ones.

[Azure Storage Explorer](http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/)

[Azure Explorer](http://www.cerebrata.com/products/azure-explorer/introduction)

2) Using powershell

Here's a simple script I'm borrowing from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn749825.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article.

```
# Azure subscription-specific variables.
$storageAccountName = "storage-account-name"
$containerName = "container-name"

# Find the local folder where this PowerShell script is stored.
$currentLocation = Get-location
$thisfolder = Split –parent $currentLocation

# Upload files in data subfolder to Azure.
$localfolder = "$thisfolder\data"
$destfolder = "data"
$storageAccountKey = (Get-AzureStorageKey -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName).Primary
$blobContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
$files = Get-ChildItem $localFolder foreach($file in $files)
{
  $fileName = "$localFolder\$file"
  $blobName = "$destfolder/$file"
  write-host "copying $fileName to $blobName"
  Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File $filename -Container $containerName -Blob $blobName -Context $blobContext -Force
} 
write-host "All files in $localFolder uploaded to $containerName!"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt reply. I want to know if my Azure account will store this 550 GB in the free azure account with 150$ credits in a month. Also, the file in some one else server, shall he install Azure Explorer there, or what?

Comment: If you have created a Locally Redundant Storage, you will pay about $13 for 550Gb. Azure charges $0,024/Gb month; Yes. He will have to install the tool or simply use powershell. There's no FTP access to storage accounts.

Comment: Thanks again for your helpful reply. Is there away to store these data for free? As you know, we have 5 Azure subscriptions for our company and every one has 150$/month to use. I just need to store this file, till we start using it in our website database.

Comment: This size no. Maybe using a trial subscription and then copying the file using AzCopy between storages.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your cooperation. I have few queries. The team try to copy the folder on the server to Azure Storage account with Azure Explorer, but it gives error message. Is it applicable to copy and paste this big 550 GB file, and will Azure Storage Account accept that? There are some blogs say that we can create VM server and use it as FTP. If I did that and used the storage account, will the files that I will upload be saved to this storage account?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend gui tools to transfer very big single files. Use powershell, but as far as storage limits go, there's nothing preventing you from transfering a file with this size. You can transfer a single file up to 500Tb. You can use a VM as FTP server to receive this file but you can't use as blob storage and file storage at the same time. Basically you would copy the files to this VM and then you'd have to move this file to a blob storage. The easiest way once the file is in an Azure VM is to use the cmd "net use z: \\storagepath...." to mount the storage. Only works inside Azure tho

Comment: Thanks for help as usual. I think that I will now remove the spending limit, and try to transfer the file with Azure Explorer. I am not very familiar with Powershell and want to finish this task soon. Do you think that Azure Explorer will do the task and you just prefer Poweshell or it will not? I received "system out of memory exception" error message from Azure Explorer before I remove spending limit, is this because spending limit was there?

Comment: Probably not. I had problems with large files before with those tools and i'm talking about a few gigs not 500gb :). It's really straight forward to use powershell for this task just search for cmd samples. Try azcopy as well. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/